# Rails 3 Form fields not submitting params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters

I am building an admin section for an app I'm working that lists businesses.  Admins can then go in and submit an email address and activate the business. So I am using a form_tag within a block like so:

```
<% for business in @businesses %>   
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="border-table"><%= business.id %></td>
    <td align="center" class="border-table"><%= business.name %></td>
    <td align="center" class="border-table"><%= business.address %></td>
    <td align="center" class="border-table"><%= business.phone %></td>
    <% @user = User.new %>
    <%= form_tag "/businesses/activate?business_id=#{business.id}", :remote => true, :method => :put do %>
        <td align="center" class="border-table" id="<%= business.id %>_email"><%= text_field_tag "email", nil, :placeholder => "email" %></td>
        <td align="center" class="border-table" id="<%= business.id %>_activate"><%= submit_tag "Activate" %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

So on a given admin page there are 25 of these forms, one for each row in the table.

The problem is, for whatever reason, the "email" param is not getting posted, just the business_id (from the path).

Is there something I am doing wrong? Are you not supposed to generate multiple similar forms using a block?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried viewing source to see how the email input is being rendered?

Comment: i have, it looks fine to me: <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" index="1" id="email">

Comment: Also why are you using a query string to pass in the business_id? That is absolutely *not* the Rails Way.

Comment: @Ryan That also isn't the Rails Way. You should be using `/businesses/:business_id/activate` as the target of your form. Check out a generated controller and follow the way Rails does things. If you're not going to follow Rails conventions, there really is no point in using Rails.

Comment: ahh excellent, thank you! I've updated my routes to make it so.  I figured out what was causing the issue too (see answer below)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i figured it out. it seems most browsers won't pass the params of a form unless it's inside the `<td>` like so:

```
<td align="center" class="border-table" id="<%= rep.id %>_email">
  <%= form_tag activate_rep_path(rep.id), :remote => true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "email", nil, :placeholder => "email", :index => rep.id %></td>
<td align="center" class="border-table" id="<%= rep.id %>_activate">
  <%= submit_tag "Activate" %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: really not sure why this got downvoted.  I updated it include the RAILS WAY path

Comment: It is bad to wrap a form across two tds (breaking the nesting of HTML tags!). Would be better if the form wraps the whole table. or else you should consider re-structuring your html structure.